# Why can't I see some mutual Facebook friends?

Tags: facebook

I share mutual friends with a lot of people on Facebook, yet on some they don’t show up. It shows that we have 12 mutual friends, but I only see 4. How does that happen? For example, one friend has her friends list hidden, but I still see two of our mutual friends (even though I know we have more like six)

Answer (score 13):

The number of mutual friends now includes mutual friends whose accounts have been disabled, but these friends are not displayed.  Also, if the person's full list of friends is hidden to you, a mutual friend who also has their full list of friends hidden to you will not be displayed as a mutual friend.

Comment: In other words, if a mutual friend's friend list is hidden, it will not be show up.

Comment: @Anwar: If either of the two people have their Friends visible to you then you will see them in Mutual Friends.  Only if both of them have their Friends hidden then you won't see them.

Answer (score 3):

**Scenario:** You are viewing Alice's friend list, who is not your Facebook friend. Bob is your mutual friend.

- If Bob shows his friend list to his friends, then you can see him as a mutual friend in her friend list
- If Bob hides his friend list to his friends, then you cannot see him as a mutual friend in her friend list
- If Alice sets her friend list as public, then you can see him as a mutual friend in her friend list, regardless of whether he hides this friend list or not

One question: what would be the reason for not seeing Alice in his friend list if I am friend with her?

Answer (score 0):

If both of your friends hide their friends list then they will not show up on your mutual friends list hence the reason for the difference in the count.